# Prequential Evaluation - IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, compiler-errors, tree, regression

I have a csv file with x and y variables. I want to do a regression and this is my code and my dataset:

[Dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q0cp.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cr6S.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuGUH.png)

Any suggestion? I need to do it according to an assessment. I am so busy helping my family due the covid outbreak ... I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing all the code, but sum_of_attribute_values is returning an empty list, whereas your code is expecting at least one element, hence indexing at 0 is returning an IndexError.